# Needed help in UIActivityIndicatorView - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiactivityindicatorview

Since i am new in iPhone i am having a litle problem. I want to use UIActivityIndicatorView in my application. Since I have bee succesfull using indicatorView but I want to display the IndicatorView with a Blur Background so that i could not click on the button on my Current activity.

Please Friends

Guide me to some tutorial or some code.

Thanks a bunch in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go this is my implementation but you can modify. Post the code in app Delegate and use anywhere in you application.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Waiting View
- (void)showWaitingView {

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(90, 190, 32, 32);
    UIActivityIndicatorView* progressInd = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [progressInd startAnimating];
    progressInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;

    frame = CGRectMake(130, 193, 140, 30);
    UILabel *waitingLable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    waitingLable.text = @"Processing...";
    waitingLable.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    waitingLable.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];;
    waitingLable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    UIView *theView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    theView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    theView.alpha = 0.7;
    theView.tag = 999;
    [theView addSubview:progressInd];
    [theView addSubview:waitingLable];

    [progressInd release];
    [waitingLable release];

    [window addSubview:[theView autorelease]];
    [window bringSubviewToFront:theView];
    [pool drain];
}

- (void)removeWaitingView {
    UIView *v = [window viewWithTag:999];
    if(v) [v removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Comment: so how should i call it from my Viewcontroller.m file??

Comment: and does this continue working on my processes. and mean while show me the waiting icon??

Comment: Yes. You can use it like this [appDelegate showWaitingView]; and [appDelegate removeWaitingView]; I assume you know how to get appDelegate in other classes.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to add a view with a *black background* and *alpha* of *0.3* or something. Then add the activity indicator above the view.

```
// an example
[self.view addSubview:aSemiTransparentBlackView];
[self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
```

Answer (score 0):

can try this also:

```
-(UIAlertView *)showActivityIndicator :(NSString *)message
{

alertViewProgress = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:message message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];       
UIActivityIndicatorView *activity =[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120,50,37,37)];
    activity.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
    [activity startAnimating];
    [alertViewProgress addSubview:activity];
    [activity release];
    [alertViewProgress show];
    return alertViewProgress;
}
```